# Why do we have to make a SELECT after an 'INSERT ALL'?

Tags: sql, oracle

As I seen on many sites, if I want to make an `INSERT ALL`, I have to finish it with a `SELECT (Like SELECT * FROM dual;)`

Why?

Comment: Usually you have to finish with a COMMIT. 
Not sure why you have a SELECT.

What sites are you referencing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subquery is mandatory per the syntax of INSERT ALL (see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2111652)

the insert clause is executed for each row returned by the subquery (i.e. the SELECT statement). SELECT * FROM dual returns a single row, so the insert_clause(s) is executed once (which is useful when you want to insert a hardcoded set of values)

Answer (score 0):

As [shown in the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2121682), the INSERT ALL synthax expects a subquery: you can not have `INSERT ALL [...] VALUES [...]`.

I suspect the SELECT from dual is a way to make a multi-insert of one row on several tables.